# SharePoint 2013 Search Crawl Not Returning Items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, crawl

We have a client that runs their website off of SharePoint 2013. They have a search service that is supposed to crawl through all pages and documents and allow users to search this content.

Their search has stopped working and only returns the main site page for only a few searches.

We have tried:

- resetting the index
- deleting the cache
- recreating the search service

After resetting the index, we have done a full crawl. The crawl only lasts ~1min. It shows one success for the website and 1 error.

The error is as follows for sitemaps://www.[website].com:90/sitemap.xml:
"The secure sockets layer (SSL) certificate sent by the server was invalid and this item will not be crawled."

Everything I have read says to ignore this. So I am not sure if this is truely an issue.

When I look at the uls logs there don't seem to be anything that stands out while doing a crawl other than:
"OpenQuery Failed with status ID: 0x800007d0. QueryPath: \Search Gatherer...".

Again everything I have read says this is not the problem.

I am new to SharePoint Search Services and this version of SharePoint is not really supported. So any pointers and advice on what to do next would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE after SSL Certificate Fix**

Sorry for the late reply. I work with a number of clients and unfortunately, this one has a lower MSA priority.

They got me their SSL Trusted Root Certificate and I added it to their SharePoint admin center. The SSL certificate error went away.

I am getting no errors now from the crawl. It comes back with 4 items. The main site, and 3 sitemap.xml.

The search still didn't not crawl the other pages, nor the documents. When you search it can only bring the main page back in results.

There is nothing I could see in the ULS logs other than the "OpenQuery Failed with status ID: 0xc0000bb8. QueryPath: ..." which happen all the time without the index reset or crawl. I plan on doing the adding the user for mssearch.exe to performance maintenance group as some suggested. But I do not think this will fix the issue that I am still not getting the content crawled.

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks all!

**Still need help :(**

Comment: You need to resolve the SSL issue. The server won't crawl it unless it is trusted, so not returning any items would be expected. You can tell the SSA to ignore SSL certificate issues, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: You can tell the SSA to ignore SSL issues but in my experience, that setting’s useless and you have to fix the SSL cert issue anyway. (It doesn’t work for expired certs, untrusted certs nor certs with incorrect SANs)